# loading SVG on android program

Tags: android, image, svg

I want to change **bitmap** images (.png)  in my **android** application to **SVG images**. I work with the android basic engine.
what is the best solution?
thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1):

SVG is not a image supported by android

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

That means you need custom code to make it work

I haven't tried myself but a quick google search and voila

http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/